# Firefox password protect on entry

Tags: windows, gratis, security, firefox

I'm looking for an add-on to the Firefox browser that will allow me to password protect the browser on startup. I would like the add-on to meet these requirements,

- Works on Windows 10 (I don't know how it wouldn't, though)
- Password can be simple and as short as a 4 digit pin
- Is gratis

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Encrypts the firefox user data directory
- Times out after a certain number of failed attempts
- Provides a log of entries and/or failed attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An add-on I have been working that meets just my requirements (not wanted features) is called StartupMaster. It's simple and easy to use where you can simply set a password and every time you load the browser, it will ask for that password before allowing entry to the browser itself. It works on Windows 10 and is gratis.

## [StartupMaster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/startupmaster/) (gratis)

> This extension is a minor enhancement for Firefox & Thunderbird. It asks your master password every time you start the application before the main window is displayed. If there is no master password set, the extension does nothing.
>
> [image: Startup Master - asking for password window]